# Display Weight under Price in Product Page & Search page

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

i need to display Product Weight under Product price in the single product page & search page on OpenCart 3.0.2.0 .

How i can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively simple if you understand the MVC (Model, View, Controller) pattern. Here are the steps required:

1. You need to add the logic for fetching the product weight in the controller file and pass it to the view `catalog/controller/product/product.php`

On line 283 (right after the price because it is a nice place for it) add this code

```php
$data['weight'] = $product_info['weight'] + 0 ;
```

(the + 0 removes the zeros and makes it looks nicer)

2. Then you need to display it in your view template file `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.twig`

on line 162 add:

```
{{weight}}
```

If you don't see the changes, that is because you have twig Cache turned on. Go to admin/dashboard and on the top right corner find the gear button. click it and click refresh cache. you can also turn off the cache while you are in development mode. http://joxi.ru/LmGewYZiwBW0zA

Comment: i did all what you say but still can't see the default weight for the product , can i give the link to see ?

Comment: Did you actually add weight parameter to the product you are testing with? you should just see the value of something like "10" 

yeah, send me a link to info@dreamvention.com