# Add product weight under price in category page

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to add the product default weight under the price in category page on OpenCart3, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a similar answer for the [weight under price in product page here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54969742/display-weight-under-price-in-product-page-search-page/54971239#54971239)

For the category page it is very much the same:

1. in file `catalog/controller/product/category.php` on `line 203` add

```php
'weight'      => $result['weight'] + 0,
```

2. in file `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.twig` on `line 142` add

```
{{product.weight}}
```

this will show the weight as such

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have good answer for the show Product weight under price in Category page here

In the category section you can following steps:

step : 1 first fall you are open file : catalog/controller/product/category.php

find below line

```
'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
```

after add or write following code

```
'weight'      => $result['weight'],
```

step : 2  open file : catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.twig

find below line

```
{% if product.rating %}
```

before add or write following code

```
<span class="text-weight" style="font-size: 12px;font-weight: 600;color: #e82a17;">weight : {{product.weight}} </span>
```

I hope my code is 100% working.if any issue you can ask to me via comment box.

[image]

Thanks You.